# Is there a smarter way to write this? React color styling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

## Want

I want to change some colors in the Material UI. In addition, I want to create a React Component that can switch colors with Props.

## Problem

I used `withStyles` to create multiple colored components. I wrapped these in another component so that I could switch between them by `props` that specify the color name.

There are long and useless repetitions.

## Code

Is there a smarter way to write this code?

```ts
import React from 'react'
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const StyledRating_Red = withStyles({
    iconFilled: {
        color: "red"
    }
})(Rating);

const StyledRating_Green = withStyles({
    iconFilled: {
        color: "green"
    }
})(Rating);

const StyledRating_Blue = withStyles({
    iconFilled: {
        color: "blue"
    }
})(Rating);

type FormRowProps = {
    scale: number;
    colorstyle: "red" | "green" | "blue";
};

const FormRow: React.FC<FormRowProps> = ({ scale, colorstyle }) => {
    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
                {("red" == colorstyle)
                    ? <StyledRating_Red
                        defaultValue={scale}
                        getLabelText={(value: number) => customIcons[value].label}/>
                    : ("green" == colorstyle)
                        ? <StyledRating_Green
                            defaultValue={scale}
                            getLabelText={(value: number) => customIcons[value].label}/>
                        : <StyledRating_Blue
                            defaultValue={scale}
                            getLabelText={(value: number) => customIcons[value].label/>
                }
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can create a **render function** that you pass a color to and that will return the result of calling `withStyles` with that color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **render function** like this:

```tsx
import React from "react";
import Rating, {RatingProps} from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core";

type ColorProp = "red" | "green" | "blue";

interface IStyledRatingProps extends RatingProps {
  color: ColorProp;
}

interface IFormRowProps {
  scale: number;
  colorStyle: ColorProp;
}

const StyledRating: React.FC<IStyledRatingProps> = ({color, ...rest}) => React.createElement(withStyles({
    iconFilled: {
        color,
    },
})(Rating), rest);

const FormRow: React.FC<IFormRowProps> = ({scale, colorStyle}) => (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <StyledRating
            readOnly // <-- TODO remove this and define `name` prop
            color={colorStyle}
            defaultValue={scale}
            getLabelText={(value: number) => "label"} // <-- TODO here was custom icons array
        />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: By the way, how would you write this in TypeScript?

Comment: color of const StyledRating is ts(7031)

Comment: @ShortArrow it is necessary to define an interface for properties, now I will edit

Comment: Mmm, I can't resolve ts(2769) on `React.createElement()`. So difficult.

Comment: @ShortArrow This is not a fatal error and everything works, but okay, I changed the answer again
[codesandbox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/xenodochial-leakey-mpltz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)